# How do i create an optional var with no value inline

Tags: swift

I have a method that returns an optional integer like this one:

```
func foo(bar:String) -> Int?
{
    if(bar == "bar")
    {
        return 42
    }
    else
    {
        var nothing:Int?
        return nothing
    }
}
```

I'd like to return *no value* without creating the var, is that possible?

```
return nothing:Int?
```

Would be something like what i would expect...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: then use: return Int?(), or just: return nil

Comment: just return nil. nil means "there is nothing" (your optional variable does not have a value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
return nil
```

You do not need to specify the type - you have provided it in the function return type already.

Comment: I am sure i tested this fist... Sorry for the obvious question - maybe someone else can use it

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
func foo(bar:String) -> Int?
{
  return bar == "bar" ? 42 : nil
}
```

to return the desired `nil`.  The expression `?:` is the most under-used in any language...